WPF Apply LUT to Gray8 picture
I've an Gray8 picture.
For the example going black to white from left to right, but in real project there is real pictures.
My final objective is paint in orange white pixels at 255 and less other at their gray8 value, only for display.
Here is a sample of all my test code
private FormatConvertedBitmap ApplyLut(List<Color> lut, BitmapSource source)
{
    FormatConvertedBitmap newFormatedBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
    newFormatedBitmapSource.BeginInit();
    newFormatedBitmapSource.Source = source;
    BitmapPalette myPalette = new BitmapPalette(lut);
    newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationPalette = myPalette;

    if (lut.Count < 6)
    {
        // If y try Indexed1, Indexed2, or Indexed4 it's the same result,
        // and for Index8, it seems that nothing his apply
        newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Indexed4; 
    }
    else
    {
        // for 256 colors list, previous PixelsFormat doesn't work
        // and for Index8, it seems that nothing his apply
        newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Indexed8;
    }

    newFormatedBitmapSource.EndInit();

    return newFormatedBitmapSource;
}

And the result:

The first image on the left is the original, the second test with 2 colors, next test with 5 colors and the final test with 256 colors.
I've read many topics,
Stackoverflow topic
Stackoverflow topic
Microsoft doc
Microsoft doc
and some other but don't anderstand some things.
First, as I understand a LUT, it would be an array, or a dictionary that associate a grey value (0 to 255) at a RGB value.
If it was that, why, on my 2 colors sample there is orange in dark value et blue in clear value?
And why for 5 colors sample, there are blended?
That's nice but not what I want.
Second, why, with 256 colors sample, nothing seems to happened?
Third, how can I apply orange to pixels at 255?
You can retrieve original image here https://www.cjoint.com/c/NDtrfpLR4uS
I expect grey pixel between [0, 254] keep their their value and pixels at 255 appear in orange when the picture is displayed.
Hover if someone knows how to do that with emgu, I'm interested too.
Thanks

FormatConvertedBitmap is trying to create a bitmap that has a different pixel format and/or color palette, but looks as similar as possible as the original.
So you do not want to create a FormatConvertedBitmap, but instead a BitmapSource with the same raw pixel buffer, but a different BitmapPalette.
Assuming the source bitmap has a Format of Indexed8 (like your sample bitmap) or Gray8, you could directly create a new BitmapSource from a copy of the original buffer like this:
var colors = Enumerable.Range(0, 255)
    .Select(i => Color.FromRgb((byte)i, (byte)i, (byte)i))
    .ToList();
colors.Add(Colors.Orange);

var palette = new BitmapPalette(colors);

var width = source.PixelWidth;
var height = source.PixelHeight;
var buffer = new byte[width * height];

source.CopyPixels(buffer, width, 0);

var result = BitmapSource.Create(
    width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Indexed8, palette, buffer, width);

The result:


Exactly what I want. Thanks a lot
